# Need to input parameters fetching from a text file and pass it to URL using python

Tags: python-2.7

Which package i need to use for passing parameters(say payloads) to URL parameters from a text file ?
i wrote few lines of code for fetching url from a text file but i need to pass parameters to that URL using another payloads text file

Comment: If you already know how to gather lines from one file, you can do the same for the second file and concatenate the string.

`url = urlpath + '?param1=' + value1 + '&param2=' + param2`

Comment: I need to send 1 payload to first parameter in url and get the result and need to send same payload to second parameter and need to save that result and so on.....timo 9

Comment: Here is my code
import urllib2
import webbrowser
out_file = open("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\10.txt","w") 
with open('C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\11.txt','r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
            password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
            handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
            password_mgr.add_password(None, line, "app", "pwd")
            opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
            r=opener.open(line)
            out_data = r.read()
            print out_data            
            out_file.write(out_data)
out_file.close()

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the code and a fake short version of the text files, so we can see the structure and get a detailed idea, Thanks.

Comment: Added my code in above comment and the text file is having URL links (you can go ahead and put any url links)